# Cucumber - Extent Reporting 3 Issue

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

While running the feature file in cucumber java 8 i am getting the below issue

> cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Couldn't load plugin class:
>   com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter. It does not implement
>   cucumber.api.Plugin
>         at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.loadClass(PluginFactory.java:179)
>         at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.pluginClass(PluginFactory.java:166)
>         at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.getPluginClass(PluginFactory.java:223)
>         at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.isFormatterName(PluginFactory.java:201)
>         at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptionsFactory.addPlugins(RuntimeOptionsFactory.java:89)
>         at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptionsFactory.buildArgsFromOptions(RuntimeOptionsFactory.java:37)
>         at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptionsFactory.create(RuntimeOptionsFactory.java:24)
>         at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.(Cucumber.java:74)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>         at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
>         at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
>         at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>         at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
>         at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>         at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:87)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:73)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:46)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:522)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)

Please find my POM FIle below

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Can anyone please help me resolving this? I am unable to proceed.

Comment: What have you done to find the issue? Maybe the used versions of `io.cucumber:*` and `com.vimalselvam:cucumber-extentsreport` are not compatible.

Comment: What is "provided" scope in your extentreports artifact?  I use JBehave with my extentreports, but I believe that cucumber integration is built-in to the standard community edition package you're using.  Not familiar with the cucumber-exentreport artifact.

Comment: Sidenote: remove the `cucumber-testng` dependency. If you are using junit, use cucumber-junit instead. Make sure to use the same cucumber version for all cucumber dependencies. Also, don't use both cucumber-java and cucumber-java8; pick one.

Comment: Have u added cucumber-core? Why do u have scope as 'provided' for extentreport dependency?